# AWK - match multiple patterns at once

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to process CSV file to find patterns like 'duser=','dhost=' and 'dproc=' and once found print next string after. I have to use pattern match first due to fact that content of CSV file is not constant. Field separators are not constant as well. Please take into consideration that CSV file contains logs in CEF format and contains much more other patterns and values. Sample log format:

```
CEF:0|Microsoft|Microsoft Windows|Windows 7|Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing:4688|A new process has been created.|Low| eventId=1010044130 externalId=4688 msg=Token Elevation Type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with User Account Control policy.Type 1 is a full token with no privileges removed or groups disabled. Type 2 is an elevated token with no privileges removed or groups disabled.Type 3 is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled. type=1 start=1523950846517 categorySignificance=/Informational categoryBehavior=/Execute/Start categoryDeviceGroup=/Operating System catdt=Operating System categoryOutcome=/Success categoryObject=/Host/Resource/Process art=1523950885975 cat=Security deviceSeverity=Audit_success rt=1523950863727 dhost=A-Win7Test.*****.net dst=**.**.**.46 destinationZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Public Address Space Zones/******* dntdom=****** oldFileHash=en_US|UTF-8 cnt=5 cs2=Process Creation cs6=TokenElevationTypeDefault (1) cs1Label=Mandatory Label cs2Label=EventlogCategory cs3Label=New Process ID cs4Label=Process Command Line cs5Label=Creator Process ID cs6Label=Token Elevation Type ahost=a-server09.****.net agt=**.**.**.9 agentZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Public Address Space Zones/******** amac=00-50-56-B8-4F-BB av=7.7.0.8044.0 atz=GMT at=winc dvchost=A-Win7Test.*****.net dvc=**.**.**.46 deviceZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Public Address Space Zones/********** deviceNtDomain=***** dtz=GMT _cefVer=0.1 aid=3AaTkhlEBABCABcfWDDqDbw\=\=
```

Ref: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/ArcSight-User-Discussions/Issue-with-Windows-Event-4688/td-p/1641345

Seems that below command works:

```
... | awk 'sub(/.*duser=/,""){print "User:",$1}
```

However, it works only for the first pattern. After execution as you can guess, there are no more lines to process. Is there any option to execute above command 3 times with different pattern to get a list of 3 columns?

I would like to achieve:

```
duser=AAA dhost=BBB dproc=CCC
duser=DDD dhost=EEE dproc=FFF
duser=GGG dhost=HHH dproc=III
```

Appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you out, we would require an example input file. Please take the [tour] and have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Don't forget to [edit] the question and provide the requested information. If not, I am convinced this question will soon be closed as _unclear_.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the link with a copy paste from your file or that example file. The reason is that links might change or vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$ cat file
duser=AAA dhost=BBB dproc=CCC
duser=DDD dhost=EEE dproc=FFF
duser=GGG dhost=HHH dproc=III

$ awk '{print gensub("duser=([^ \t,]+)[ \t,]+dhost=([^ \t,]+)[ \t,]+dproc=([^ \t,]+)", "User: \\1, Host: \\2, Proc: \\3
", 1);}' file
User: AAA, Host: BBB, Proc: CCC
User: DDD, Host: EEE, Proc: FFF
User: GGG, Host: HHH, Proc: III
```

If the three parts are in different positions and with different sequences, then try this:

```
awk '{match($0,"duser=([^ \t,]+)",user);  match($0,"dhost=([^ \t,]+)",host);  match($0,"dproc=([^ \t,]+)",proc);  print "User: " user[1] ", Host: " host[1] ", Proc: " proc[1];}' file
```

Please read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you ask another question.

Comment: This is probably not correct as the OP states that the input is a CSV file.

Comment: @kvantour  He stated `Field separators are not constant as well.`. However I already included comma separated CSVs by `[ \t,]`

Comment: Unfortunately, seems that it doesn't work as expected. Maybe this is a misunderstanding. The csv contains much more values and patterns 'duser', 'dhost' and 'dport' are not at the same positions in every single line.

Comment: @Tiw now it works like a harm! amazing job, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl.

```
$ cat lack_of_threat.txt
duser=AAA dhost=BBB dproc=CCC
duser=DDD dhost=EEE dproc=FFF
duser=GGG dhost=HHH dproc=III
$ perl -ne ' /duser=(\S+)\s*dhost=(\S+)\s*dproc=(\S+)/; print "User:$1, Host:$2, Proc:$3\n" ' lack_of_threat.txt
User:AAA, Host:BBB, Proc:CCC
User:DDD, Host:EEE, Proc:FFF
User:GGG, Host:HHH, Proc:III
$
```

Comment: I'm getting empty list:


`User:, Host:, Proc:
User:, Host:, Proc:
User:, Host:, Proc:
User:, Host:, Proc:
User:, Host:, Proc:`

Comment: is your input file same as what I used in my answer?.